# Paging and filtering on Kendo grid bound to WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid which is bound to a WebAPI endpoint and I want to perform server-side paging and filtering. I am attempting to use the `ToDataSourceResult()` extension. However, the grid does not render the results.

I have verified in the controller that the response does have the correct items on the Data member.

My view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@(
    Html.Kendo().Grid<CMDB.Entities.Asset>()
    .Name("AssetGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(c => c.AssetTypeInfo.Meaning);
        col.Bound(c => c.AssetSubTypeInfo.Meaning);
        col.Bound(c => c.Name);
        col.Bound(c => c.ManagerInfo.DisplayName);
        col.Bound(c => c.DirectorInfo.DisplayName);
        col.Bound(c => c.BusinessOwnerInfo.DisplayName);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 300px" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(p => p
        .PageSizes(true)
        .Refresh(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .WebApi()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultAPI",
        new { controller = "Values", action = "SearchAssets" })))
    ))
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public DataSourceResult SearchAssets([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (var ctx = new Data.DBContext())
    {
        var data = (from a in ctx.Query<Entities.Asset>()
                   select a);
        var rr = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return rr;
    }     
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine as long as I use a model OTHER THAN my entity. Does this possibly have something to do with the navigation properties in my entity?

Comment: Upon further investigation, this seems to be caused by the navigation properties in my entity. They don't get materialized when I return the DataSourceResult. If I perform the exact same steps but return a class that has the same properties (that aren't virtual) it works perfectly.  I feel like there's something I'm missing though.  I don't think this is right.

Comment: Kendo Grid never works with your entity. You need to use a ViewModel or a DTO.